# embedded linux and powering usb stick

Tags: linux, usb, embedded, power-management

I have a problem where I need to read a usb-stick or a usb keyboard: When I plug in the USB stick or keyboard I can't get power to the device. `dmesg` says nothing

I tried:

```
for device in $(ls /sys/bus/usb/devices/*/product); 
  do echo $device
  cat $device;
done
```

for getting information in console and I get this output:

```
/sys/bus/usb/devices/usb1/product
Freescale On-Chip EHCI Host Controller
```

I can't see any kingston usb stick or keyboard.

Quesitons:

1. How can I power my usb device `mdev` or `/sys/bus/usb/devices/*/power`
2. How to read data from keyboard or usb stick.

Comment: which embeded and which unix distribution do you use?

Comment: Linux version 2.6.35.3 (panu@ubuntu) (gcc version 4.4.1 (Sourcery G++ Lite 2010q1-202) ) #1 PREEMPT 
Linux 2.6.35.3 armv5tejl

Built with buildroot

Comment: Some very small (thin) USB sticks can be inserted upside down; try turning the usb stick over...

Answer (score 0):

observe the output in syslog with:

```
tail -f /var/log/syslog
```

while plugging in and out the USB-device.

If you have no syslog, install some [Logging framework for embedded linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/338813/logging-frameworks-for-embedded-linux)

Comment: there is no syslog in this embbedded linux

Comment: maybe you find a simple logging framework in my edit

Comment: Theres no logs for usb when connecting usb stick.

Answer (score 0):

Solution wasn't simple.

I need to configurate /sys/class/gpio/ for enabling internal 5V step-up regulator.